# NSIS installer. Why do I get the warning "!verbose: pop failed"?

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

I am creating a new installer for an updated software version using the NSIS script from the old one. I am compiling the old script as is and it pops 2 warnings:

```
!verbose: Pop failed, stack is empty (macro:MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE:2)
!verbose: Pop failed, stack is empty (macro:MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE:24)
```

The script in which these warnings prompt me is this (the lines in which I receive the warnings are the `!verbose pop`) :

```
!macro MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE

  !verbose pop

  !ifdef MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT & MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY & MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_VALUENAME

    ReadRegStr $MUI_TEMP1 "${MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT}" "${MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY}" "${MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_VALUENAME}"
    StrCmp $MUI_TEMP1 "" 0 mui.ungetlanguage_setlang

  !endif

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY

  !ifdef MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT & MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY & MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_VALUENAME

    Goto mui.ungetlanguage_done

    mui.ungetlanguage_setlang:
      StrCpy $LANGUAGE $MUI_TEMP1

    mui.ungetlanguage_done:

  !endif

  !verbose pop

!macroend
```

Are these warnings worth worrying for? And if yes, what should I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: NSIS version? MUI v1 or v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in NSIS, the first pop should be a push.

You can fix it by manually pushing first to hide the bug:

```
!verbose push
!verbose push
!insertmacro MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE
```

or fix the .nsh file by replacing the first pop with:

```
!verbose push
!verbose ${MUI_VERBOSE}
```

The warning is not a big deal, it might affect the compiler text output in unexpected ways but it has no effect on the generated installer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!